# Not able to clickon Redelivery menuItem in http://www.royalmail.com/

Tags: selenium

Selenium WebDriver code being used.
FreeToPay is class representing Home Webpage of http://www.royalmail.com/
getWebDriver is get method to get webdriver instance.

```
  WebElement Menu=FreeToPay.getWebDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Receiving mail"));
        //Sub menu 
        WebElement MenuItem=FreeToPay.getWebDriver().findElement(By.linkText("Redelivery"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
        Actions hoverOverRegistrar = builder.moveToElement(Menu);
        hoverOverRegistrar.build().perform();


        MenuItem.click();
```

Comment: well, I got to the page and I do not see the menu with "Receiving mail" topic ... probably the page got updated?

Comment: There is not 'Receiving Mail' link anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot see the link in the page, there are my tips:

- Try that manually and exactly follow whats in the script. If you cannot do it manually, you will probably have to update the script
- There is possibly typo in the code:

you define WebElement called `MenuItem` but later on you try to hover over something which is called `Menu` only:

```
Actions hoverOverRegistrar = builder.moveToElement(Menu);
```

Maybe try to replace it by

```
Actions hoverOverRegistrar = builder.moveToElement(MenuItem);
```

BTW one last advice: The variables should start with lowercase letter - see [this advice](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: Menu is webelement in main navigator and MenuItem is another subemenu.Script need to hover on Menu and then submenu need to be clicked.

Comment: Did you try it manually? Check the page by yourself and then try to next step